# Does the supremum only apply to $\mathbb{R}$ and not to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My professor stated that the supremum only applies to $\mathbb{R}$ and not to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This got me thinking what exactly would the supremum mean in regards to $\mathbb{R}^n$?  Is there a concept that is analogous to the supremum in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

For example, suppose that $A$ is a clopen subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\emptyset \ne A \ne \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a \in A$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash A$.  Let's suppose that $a < b$.

What would $c=$sup$(A \cap [a,b])$ even mean?  Is this supposed to be the largest intersection?  If so wouldn't $c=$max$(A \cap [a,b])$ make more sense?  Or is there a better notation?

Thank you.

Comment: What does it mean for $a<b$ when $a,b\in\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Supremum can be apply over every ordered set!

Comment: There do exist orders on $\Bbb R^n$, for example [lexicographic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), in which case supremum does indeed make sense, but not necessarily the same sense that you are used to.  Once you leave $\Bbb R$ and go to $\Bbb R^n$, there is no one single *canonical* order that you can use and you will need to specify *which* order you are using before any further discussion can take place.

Comment: Even partial orders with some 'completeness' condition.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews so what is someone implying in their proof when they use notation like $c=$sup$(A \cap [a,b])$?  I see people on this board using notation such as this...what are they implying? $c=$max$(A \cap [a,b])$?

Comment: The largest element in the interval $[a,b]$ which is also in $A$ (*or more correctly, the supremum of the set of elements in the interval $[a,b]$ and $A$*).  You should note that "intervals" don't make as much sense to talk about in $\Bbb R^n$, but you could talk about boxes in a similar way.  The same convenient properties of order and closedness don't necessarily translate however, so you would never see $sup(A\cap [a,b])$ in a discussion about $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: Intervals make sense to talk about in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a linear algebraic sense. For example, for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $[x,y] = \{\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y: 0\leq \lambda\leq 1\}$. You are still lacking the order stucture you want to define sup though.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, "intervals" don't make much sense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is why I get confused when somebody uses sup in a proof in regards to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  When you say boxes is this the same as a cell (using Elements of Real Analysis by Bartle)?  Would the notion of a largest cell with the given norm make some sense?  My appologies if I'm struggling.  Undergraduate with first course in Real Analysis.

Comment: @IdleMathGuy If they are using $\sup(A\cap [a,b])$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with $n>1$ they'd have to define what they mean.

Comment: @IdleMathGuy to me, a "box" in $\Bbb R^n$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ of the form $I=[a_1,a_2]\times [b_1,b_2]\times \dots \times [n_1,n_2]$.  If we were to use lexicographic ordering, the sup of $I$ would be $(a_2,b_2,\dots,n_2)$, but if we were to ask about the sup of some $A\cap I$, that could get confusing quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to venture a bit into the non-standard, I would say that the supremum on $\mathbb{R}^n$ *does* exist, although I have not normally seen the concept used in practical maths.

First, some base facts. The word *supremum* is a concept defined in the context of *orderings on sets*. The supremum property is that "every set has a least upper bound". This is true of the extended reals, $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$. (And though almost true, not quite true of the reals themselves.)

In order to ask, "does the supremum exist in $\mathbb{R}^n$ too?", we have to first have an *ordering* on $\mathbb{R}^n$ -- what it means for $x$ to be less than $y$. There are two such orderings that are most natural and common:

**1. Coordinate-Wise Ordering** This is a *partial* ordering on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^n$.
Let us consider the example of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^3$.
We define that $(x,y,z) \le (x',y',z')$ whenever $x \le x'$ AND $y \le y'$ AND $z \le z'$.

**2. Lexicographic Ordering** This is a total ordering on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^n$.
The way it works is like ordering words in a dictionary.
We define that $(x,y,z) \le (x',y',z')$ as follows.
First, we compare the first coordinate. If $x < x'$, then $(x,y,z) \le (x',y',z')$ (regardless of $y,z,y',z'$).
Second, if $x = x'$, then we look to the second coordinate as a tie-breaker: if $x = x'$ and $y < y'$, then $(x,y,z) \le (x',y',z')$. And so on. For instance, $(1,4,3) \le (1,5,1)$, and $(2,10,10) \le (3,1,1)$.
This ordering includes the ordering in (1), but includes a lot more as well. This ordering also distinguishes between first coordinate, second coordinate, and so on, so in this sense it is not symmetric (it treats different dimensions differently).

**Under both of these orderings, the supremum of any set exists.**
To find the supremum in ordering (1), one takes the supremum in each coordinate of the points' values in that coordinate. To find the supremum in ordering (2), one takes the supremum in the first coordinate to first, and then the supremum in the second coordinate *of points whose first coordinate is the first supremum*, and so on.
Thus it can be meaningful to speak of the supremum in $\mathbb{R}^n$.